# Binomial sum closed formula

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I was wondering if a closed formula, with  few terms in $n$ and $k$, is known for
$$f(n,k):=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\left(\begin{array}{c}nk \\ ni\end{array}\right),$$
for arbitrary positive  integers $n$ and $k$. If not, what if we fix some relatively
small $n>2$, say $n=4,5,\ldots$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any polynomial $P(x)$, the sum of the coefficients of $1$, $x^n$, $x^{2n}$, ... in $P$ is $\frac{1}{n} \left( P(1) + P(\exp(2\pi i / n)) + P(\exp(4\pi i / n)) + \ldots + P(\exp(2(n - 1)\pi i / n))\right)$.  (That is, evaluate $P$ at the complex $n$th roots of $1$, add them up, and divide by $n$.)  In math competition circles this is sometimes called the "root of unity filter", see e.g. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1340h1003741_roots_of_unity_filter .  In your case $P(x) = (1 + x)^{nk}$, and then you should subtract $1$ at the end because you've left off the $i = 0$ term.